# JSON postback to c# webmethod add literal control

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webmethod

I'm learning about webmethods and posting back to them using JSON, I've got the following below, but it says it can't find the webmethod (404). Can't see where I'm going wrong, thanks.

In the page javascript:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $(".FilterResults").click(function () {
                   var topic = $(".DropDownList1").val();
                   var number = $(".DropDownList2").val();
                   var month = $(".DropDownList3").val();
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "filterresultshold.asmx/filterresults",
                       data: "{'args': '" + topic + "'}",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (msg) {
                           // If you return something from the method, it can be accessed via msg.d                
                       }
                   });

                   // To prevent the postback
                   return false;
               });
           });
</script>
```

In the ascx:

```xml
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="Text to display" mode="PassThrough" runat="server" /></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" class="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" class="DropDownList2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" class="DropDownList3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="FilterResults" class="FilterResults" runat="server" Text="Fill DropDownList" />
    </div>
</form>
```

In the code behind:

```cs
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for filterresults
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class filterresultshold : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public void filterresults(string args)
    {
        string[] data = args.Trim().Split(',');
        string topic = data[0];
        string number = data[1];
        string month = data[2];
        string control = "<umbraco:Macro alias='pdfarchivelist' runat='server' topic='" + topic + "' number='" + number + "' month='" + month + "'></umbraco:Macro>";
        //LiteralControl literal = new LiteralControl(control);
        //PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
        //PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(literal);
    }

}
```

Then in the .ascx code behind:

```cs
public partial class usercontrols_pdfarea : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // Populate Drops
            var rootNode = uQuery.GetRootNode();
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELEZIONA NUMERO"));
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELEZIONA MESE"));
            DropDownList3.Items.Add(new ListItem("SELEZIONA ARGOMENTO"));

            //display the password on the Gallery Folder in the media area
            var startMedia = uQuery.GetMediaByName("pdfs").FirstOrDefault();
            var DropList = rootNode.GetDescendantNodes().Where(x => x.NodeTypeAlias == "File");

            foreach (var item in startMedia.Children)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.getProperty("number").Value.ToString())); //NUMBER
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.getProperty("month").Value.ToString())); //MONTH
            }

            foreach (var item in startMedia.Children.Select(p => p.GetPropertyAsString("topic")).Distinct().ToList())
            {
                DropDownList3.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you are adding control through service?

Comment: Is your **filterresults** method written in _ascx_ code behind? I think you need to write the web method in your _aspx_ code behind.

Comment: Are you able to get a response - error or otherwise - by browsing to the URL?

Comment: I've updated it to use a webservice, and placed the webmethod code in the webservice file, and updated the javascript to point to it, but get a 500 internal service error.

Answer (score 1):

```
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class filterresultshold : System.Web.Services.WebService {
```

Just do what suggested in comment

BTW, the `filterresults` shouldn't be static

Answer (score 0):

for get your web method you use this code

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Default.aspx/filterresults",
                   data: "{'args': '" + topic + "'}",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (msg) {
                       // If you return something from the method, it can be accessed via msg.d                
                   }
               });
```

i think you should little bit changes like this

```
$.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Default.aspx/filterresults",
                   data: '{args:"' + topic + '"}',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function (msg) {
                       // If you return something from the method, it can be accessed via msg.d                
                   }
```

i think this will help you.....
                   });

Answer (score 0):

if your script is located in a subfolder, you need to use an absolute path:

```
url: "/filterresults.asmx/filterresults",
```

Answer (score 0):

if you script file is located in the same folder as filterresults.asmx file, then you url is ok, but if not, you need to write the correct path e.g an absolute path like below:

```
url: "/services/filterresults.asmx/filterresults",
```

You also need to define your webservice as a script service to allow ajax calls, like below:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class filterresultshold : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

And remove the `static` keyword from your webmethod.
Then  add the following on your web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = 
    System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string filterresults(string args)
```

**Finally** make sure you have following elements in your web.config in  section that tells webservices to listen to the Http Post calls:

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks, getting closer, I'm still getting a 500 internal server error, think it might not be passing the dropdownlist values properly, I tried var topic = $("#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>").val(); but I get a "The name 'DropDownList1' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Press F12 if you use have FireBug installed on your Firefox, or if you use Chrome, and under **Net --> XHR --> Post** see what request is sent.

Comment: thanks, I get a Could not create type 'filterresults'.
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetType(String typeName) error

Comment: Did you uncomment `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` at top of your webservice class?

Comment: Do you have to declare the webmethod service in the web.config or the ascx's scriptmanager or something?

Comment: See the updated answer. I think you need to tell that webservice should listen to HTTP Post calls in the your asp.net web.config file

Comment: I still get a No web service found at: /filterresultshold.asmx error, hmm.